# Javascript selecting nth element but excluding some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following markup:

```
<div class="body">
     <p>...<p>
     <p>...<p>
     <blockquote>
          <p>...<p>
     </blockquote>
     <p>...<p>
     <p>...<p>
</div>
```

I want to select the first `<p>` element. I can do this with:

```
$( ".body p:nth-child(1)
```

However if I wanted to select the 3rd

(excluding the blockquote) this will not work:

```
$( ".body p:nth-child(3)
```

I tried using nth-type, but if I do:

```
$( ".body p:nth-of-type(1)
```

It will select the first

in the body and also the next p in block quote.

I need to be able to exclude or ignore the blockquote. Would it work if I read the dom into a variable and removed the blockquote before calling nth-child?

Comment: What would qualify as the third `<p>` element, are you referring to the one that is inside the `blockquote` element (3 overall) or the right after the `blockquote` element (3 direct `p` element child of `div class="body"`)?

Comment: Use a child combinator: `$('.body > p:nth-of-type(3)')`

Comment: @nickzoum I was referring to the 3rd direct descendent of the body.

Comment: @Teemu the child combinator works perfectly.

Comment: Note that in your first example `$(".body p:nth-child(1)")` you'll get *two* results https://jsfiddle.net/vLxzapfq/ - you *need* the `>` if you only want direct descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, which returns an array of elements, you can avoid the quirks of the CSS `nth-...` rules. All you really need is a selector that only selects the elements you want.

e.g. `.body > p` which only matches direct children of the body class

then select the third element using jQuery's `.eq(2)` (It's 0 indexed, so `2` is the 3rd matching element)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".body > p").eq(2).text("New text")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>3</p>
  </blockquote>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the nth-direct child of an element with a specific tag (doesn't work with classnames, ids etc.) you can use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). Example:

```js
$(".body p:nth-of-type(3)")[0].textContent = "Here";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>...</p>
  </blockquote>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately you can't yet get the nth element specifying a certain condition with pure css selectors, however you could just get the 3rd element of the array. Example:

```js
$(".body p")[2].textContent = "Changed Overall 3rd";
$(".body>p")[2].textContent = "Changed Direct 3rd";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>...</p>
  </blockquote>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```